# Dealing with categorical target in neural networks (Deep Learning)

Tags: python, deep-learning

I need to predict the Diagnosis (Target ) which is a categorical feature that has 5 categories (Common cold, Influenza, Fracture, Headache, Other ) by using a sequential neural network.
I try to do one hot encoding for it like other categorical features which split the Diagnosis into 5 new columns so this is the code for the neural network which gives me 20% accuracy, I don't know how to deal with this target Knowing I am sure about my preprocessing is true.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units = 512, activation='relu', input_shape=(20,)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units = 512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units = 5, activation='softmax'))
```

find a solution to the categorical target

Comment: You need to provide us with more details, like your training-val curve, your data samples, and minimal reproducible code. Only then we can answer your question, right now it's very vague

Comment: @musabbir ,, Is it right to give you my code and the dataset? [the code link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C0njFSS1gu6vIOoiyKkNFaPzhNwI3rp8/view?usp=drive_link) [the dataset link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mGYDQdjkVyEUVfuRL2QQT2Nzg8XiJ1DP/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: I said a data samples, not your whole dataset. otherwise how would we reproduce your code?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know what you want me to do, I am new here thank you for your patience. @Musabbir

Comment: can you please help me, I've been working on it for a long long time and tried different methods and all of them didn't work

Comment: Hello, I have fixed the issues with your second model, which classifies the likelihood of Diabetes. I will post is here.

Comment: I also have a concern, why are you converting all your `gender==others` to male or female? this way you are corrupting the data. and are you absolutely certain that your preprocessing steps are correct?

Comment: I really really appreciate your work and thank you. I read if the sex is encoded so that Male = -1 and Female =+1 this gives me better performance, but it seems I forgot to do that, and for the preprocessing, I think I did my best by handling the missing data, Normalization, Remove outliers, and Encoding the categorical but this is my first project on this field and I'm still learning, so I don't exactly know if these steps are correct.
Again thank you a lot

Comment: you are welcome! just do one-hot-encoding for gender too. let me know if you need any more help! and best of luck with all these, just stick to it and you will do great!

Comment: For the first model, I had an idea that what if I replace the categories inside the Diagnosis column with numbers from 1 to 5, so by this way I could treat numbers, not categories but when I did this the model didn't work Instead it printed all the values in Diagnosis column from 1 to 5

Comment: Thank you for your kindness and interest I really appreciate it and you helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the low accuracy issue with your second model, here's my solution:

- I applied L2 regularizations in the input and hidden layers to prevent overfitting.
- Dropout layers are used to randomly drop a fraction of neurons during training, to prevent co-adaptation of neurons.
- SGD instead of Adam optimizer is used with a learning rate of 0.01 to slow-down the learning more
- Binary crossentropy loss is used for binary classification.
- I also added early stopping, which stops training if the validation loss does not improve for a certain number of epochs (5 in this case).

```
## Nural network
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2
from keras import backend as K

# Clear the Keras backend session
K.clear_session()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu', input_shape=(20,), kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(units=16, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01)))
model.add(Dense(units=8, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=0.01), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, mode='min', restore_best_weights=True)
history = model.fit(X_train2, y_train2, epochs=100, validation_data=(X_valid2, y_valid2), callbacks=[early_stopping], verbose=1)

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_valid2, y_valid2)
print(f'Test Loss: {loss:.4f}, Test Accuracy: {accuracy:.4f}')
```

Output

```
Test Loss: 0.3528, Test Accuracy: 0.8445
```

Here's your training-validation accuracy and loss graphs:

[image]

[image]

P.S. this is a crude-solution to give you and idea of what changes you can make, definitely not the best one